# Why can't I specify the xycoords='axes fraction'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why can't I specify the xycoords in `text()` according to [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html)? I just want the text to the upper left of the figure. However I don't want to use the default 'data' coords. The error is:

> AttributeError: Unknown property xycoords

Here is the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(a,x):
    return a*x
def g(a,x):
    return 5*a*x

const=[1,2,3]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
colors=['r','b','g']
labels=[r'$a=1$',r'$a=2$',r'$a=3$']
xArray=np.linspace(0,2,20)
for i in const:
    ax.plot(xArray,f(i,xArray),color=colors[i-1],label=labels[i-1])
    ax.plot(xArray,g(i,xArray),color=colors[i-1],ls='--')

ax.text(-0.1, 1.1 ,'(a)',size=20,weight='bold',xycoords='axes fraction')
ax.legend(loc=0)    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Because you are trying to use the `annotate` api with `text`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @tcaswell said in comments, `xycoords` is a kwarg for `annotate`, and not `text`.

To achieve what you want, you can use the `transform` kwarg. To use axes fraction coords, use `transform = ax.transAxes`.

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) for `text` :

> The default transform specifies that text is in data coords, alternatively, you can specify text in axis coords (0,0 is lower-left and 1,1 is upper-right). The example below places text in the center of the axes:

```
ax.text(0.5, 0.5,'matplotlib', horizontalalignment='center',
      verticalalignment='center',
      transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because [`matplotlib.text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html) != [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text).

This is due to the following lines:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
```

So `ax` is pointing to `plt` which is `matplotlib.pyplot`, the second link.

The following will work fine `ax.text(-0.1, 1.1 ,'(a)',size=20,weight='bold')`

Comment: However, I want the coordinates to be the axes fraction. This is the data fraction